# Is it bad idea to check the generic type with "this.getClass().getMethod()"?

Tags: java

I have a class:

```
public class EventListener<T extends Event> {

    private final EventHandler<T> handler;

    public EventListener(EventHandler<T> handler) {
        if (handler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public boolean isApplicable(Event event) {
        try {
            this.getClass().getMethod("onEvent", event.getClass());
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void onEvent(T event) {
        handler.handle(event);
    }
}
```

Before an invocation of the onEvent(T event) method I need to call the isApplicable(Event event) method to check that the listener could handle this event.

I don't want to increase a number of  the constructor's parameters in such way:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

     private final Class<T> type;

     public GenericClass(Class<T> type) {
          this.type = type;
     }

     public Class<T> getMyType() {
         return this.type;
     }
}
```

Listeners for different events will be stored in the same list. So I need some tool to check that the listener could handle the event from the list.

```
public class EventService extends Service {

    private final ArrayList<EventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public EventService(ServiceContainer serviceContainer) {
        super(serviceContainer);
    }

    public ArrayList<EventListener> getListeners() {
        return listeners;
    }

    public <T extends Event> void trigger(T event) {
        listeners.stream().forEach((listener) -> {
            if (listener.isApplicable(event)) {
                listener.onEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant code to put in this method:

```
public boolean isApplicable(Event event) {
    try {
        this.getClass().getMethod("onEvent", event.getClass());
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make Event an interface, declare the onEvent method , or make it abstract and define onEvent. This way, it is not necessary to check for isApplicable or create a new interface and declare onEvent there. All listeners should implement this new interface

Comment: What exactly *is* your issue? The code you've posted will fail for all derived classes of `Event` unless an appropriate `onEvent()` method overload for that derived class has been provided. Is that the intention?

Comment: I made some clarifications in the question. Thanks for the replying. The result added as an answer marked as "Finally:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code should unless your event is an instance of `Event` and not of a class inheriting it...which is impossible if `Event` is an interface or an abstract class.

To keep the same kind of "philosophy", I would pass the expected class as constructor argument and check if the event is an instance of this class.

```
 public class EventListener<T extends Event> {

    private final EventHandler<T> handler;
    private final Class<T> eventClass;

    public EventListener(EventHandler<T> handler, Class<T> eventClass) {
        if (handler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (eventClass == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.handler = handler;
        this.eventClass = eventClass;
    }

    public boolean isApplicable(Event event) {
        return this.eventClass.isInstance(event);
    }

    public void onEvent(T event) {
        handler.handle(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's seems it's the most right way nevertheless first version of the code was working too. The EventListener plays the filter role so I decided to completely  move the filtering logic to the EventListener. I removed isApplicable(Event event) method and added one more class. I didn't want to do this due a double EventChildClass writing "new ListenerClass<EventChildClass>(EventChildClass.class,...)" finally I have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally:

```
public class EventService extends Service {

    private final ArrayList<EventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public EventService(ServiceContainer serviceContainer) {
        super(serviceContainer);
    }

    public ArrayList<EventListener> getListeners() {
        return listeners;
    }

    public <T extends Event> void trigger(T event) {
        listeners.stream().forEach((listener) -> {
            listener.onEvent(event);
        });
    }
}

public class EventListener {

    private final Consumer<Event> handler;

    public EventListener(Consumer<Event> handler) {
        if (handler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        handler.accept(event);
    }
}

public class SpecifiedEventListener<T extends Event> extends EventListener {

    private final Class<T> eventClass;

    public SpecifiedEventListener(Class<T> eventClass, Consumer<T> handler) {
        super((Event event) -> {
            handler.accept((T) event);
        });
        if (eventClass == null
                || handler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.eventClass = eventClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.getClass().isAssignableFrom(eventClass)) {
            super.onEvent(event);
        }
    }

    public Class<T> getEventClass() {
        return eventClass;
    }

}
```